# How to update an object (associative array) in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a corpus of text spread over 180,000 text files, and I want to build a simple index of the words in Mongo. Each article has a uniqueID and is already tokenized. Ideally, each entry in my index would like like this:

```
{ 
  _id: "shuttle",
  instances: {
   article_1: 5,
   article_890: 1,
   article_3001: 10
  }
}
```

The number refers to the number of times the word appear in the article identified in the key.

I'm iterating through the articles in Node. The first time the program sees the word, it is not in the collection.

For the sake of speed, I would like to tally about 1000 articles at a time. So I'll have an array of tokens and an object of their instances for those 1000 articles, and I need to combine that object with the one in Mongo for all the previous batches of articles--and create that document for the token if it doesn't exist.

How to I combine objects or create them in Mongo?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the scope of the question -- are you familiar with how to create a document in mongo via node (meaning any document with any values)?  Or are you asking how to update an existing document?

Comment: Sure, creating a document is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add data to an existing array in mongo, you need to use "update" and then $push (for an array) or #addToSet (if you want uniqueness), or simply $set to add data not in a list.

UPDATE: in your case - this is not an array, but a key-value to be added, so have a look at this example:
to add data: article_300:3, to item with _id:awesomeWord,
you'll need to run query:

`db.collection.update({"_id":"awesomeWord"},{"instances":{$set: {NEW_KEY : NEW_VALUE}}},false,true);`

where NEW_KEY is article_300
and NEW_VALUE is 3

does this answer your question?